# Menu bar missing on second screen after El Capitan update 10.11.5

Tags: macos, software-update, menu-bar

I was on El Capitan 10.11.4 and just updated to 10.11.5.  Now the menu bar is missing on my second screen which is an enormous pain in the apple.

I have tried:

- Searching Google and AskDifferent and wading through many answers for much older OSX versions that no longer are relavent
- Rebooting
- Confirming that it's not just my display setup hiding the menu bar above the visible area
- Moving different apps into the second screen
- Turning off and on the System Preferences > General > Automatically hide and show the menu bar setting
- Turning on mirroring and then turning it off
- Killing and relaunching Finder
- Petitioning the ghost of Steve Jobs for help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You only get a menu bar on anything other than your primary monitor if you have
System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces checked.

It's not a setting to idly switch on & off if you have a very specific setup because it can seriously mess up your workflow... I did it once before to test a feature for SE, took me days to get my 12 spaces back together :(

Comment: gah -- upgrade must have unchecked that magically >:(

Comment: Glad that got it - I'll edit my answer to remove the assumption.